# How to count Figures and Tables by Subsections - if the section has a subsection?

Tags: amsmath, counters

Is it possible to change the code in my MWE so that all figures in sections, which are not in subsections get no zero, like Figure 1.0.1: Testfig should be Figure 1.1: Testfig. (i.e., just counting within the section). I only have sessions without subsections, as in the MWE, when then no more subsections come.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} %add graphs


\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} 

\counterwithin{table}{subsection}
\counterwithin{figure}{subsection}
\setcounter{section}{0}

\numberwithin{table}{subsection}
\numberwithin{figure}{subsection}


\title{test-seclabels}

\date{September 2023}
\date{author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\begin{figure}[htbp!]
\centering
\includegraphics{x.pdf} 

\caption{Testfig.} 
 \label{fig:testlabel}
\end{figure}

\section{Second Section}
\subsection{Second Section Sub1}
\begin{figure}[htbp!]
\centering
\includegraphics{x.pdf} 

\caption{Testfig2} 
 \label{fig:nolabel}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: it's not hard to do, basically `\renewcommand\thefigure{\ifnum\value{subsection}>0 \thesubsection\else\thesection\fi.\arabic{figure}}` but it's pretty confusing for the reader, I would just number figures with sections rather than within subsections.

Comment: You could also use `\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection\ALPH{aubsection}}` for greater clarity.

Comment: You are right, David. THanks. Would you please enter the code as an answer so I can please accept it.